# Padding the iterator in a for loop

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pad the iterator in a for loop using PowerShell, but I get an error message.

Normal padding works fine:

```
$mytext = "Test"
Write-Host $mytext.PadLeft(5, "0")
# Output: 0Test
```

But using the iterator doesn't work:

```
for ($i=1; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
  Write-Host $i.PadLeft(2, "0")
}
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'PadLeft'.

Not even if I copy the iterator into a variable before padding:

```
for ($i=1; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
  $Iterator = $i
  Write-Host $Iterator.PadLeft(2, "0")
}
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'PadLeft'.

Is it impossible to use `PadLeft()` in a `for` loop at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because `$i` is an `integer` and as the error message tells you, it doesn't contain a `PadLeft` method. Anyway, you could cast the `integer` to a string:

```
for ($i=1; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
  $Iterator = [string]$i
  Write-Host $Iterator.PadLeft(2, "0")
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, i'm so stupid, thanks... Somehow i read it as "System32" in the error message and misinterpreted the whole thing.